# How to create a custom ios-charts highlight marker with xib?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

So, I'm trying to create a custom marker from a xib file. I'm looking to the [RadarMarkerView](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo/Classes/Components/RadarMarkerView.swift) sample, it is basically the same thing. The problem is that the program compiles but the marker does not show up.

This is my custom marker class

```
open class DailyMarker: MarkerView {

        @IBOutlet weak var powerLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!

        override open func awakeFromNib() {
            self.offset.x = -self.frame.size.width / 2.0
            self.offset.y = -self.frame.size.height - 7.0
        }
        open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
            powerLabel?.text = String.init(format: "%.2f kWh", entry.y)
            hourLabel?.text = "Hora"
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

I have created a xib with the same name "DailyMarker.xib" and in the Custom Class field I set to DailyMarker.

Here is the Chart code where I set the marker

```
let dailyMarker: DailyMarker = DailyMarker()
dailyMarker.chartView = lineChartView
lineChartView.marker = dailyMarker
```

I just want to create a rounded marker with borders. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I Got it to work!

I think it was missing the .viewFromXib in the file that I was instantiating the graph. That's my updated code

```
let dailyMarker: DailyMarker = (DailyMarker.viewFromXib() as? DailyMarker)!
dailyMarker.chartView = lineChartView
lineChartView.marker = dailyMarker
```

Remembering that on the xib file inspector you put the class of the view the same of the swift file. In this case it was DailyMarker. There is no need to set the Placeholder owner.